# How to select column value with other name without using Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I select column Value with other name without using Alias

As My question,I have table

```
      empId  Salary
      1       10000
      2       20000
```

and I want to show empId, Salary, Salary  as total without using any alias.

```
      empId  Salary   Total
      1       10000   10000
      2       20000   20000
```

This Question was asked in a Meeting

Comment: Why "without using any alias?" Where are you showing this output? Using an alias is **the** correct way to do it if you're asking about raw SQL output.

Comment: That's contradictory. You can't see a column which is not there in your table. And there comes the use of 'Alias'

Comment: whats wrong with using alias? specifying that can help others understand your problem better.

Comment: @MattBall I face this question in an interview

Comment: Do you remember the exact wording of the question? Because I feel like we are missing a critical detail here ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. The only way you can do for both columns to be shown are

- alter the table and rename the columnName
- supply `ALIAS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do directly ,you can create "VIEW" on that table .

Example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW xx_emp_v
                      ( empId
                      , Salary
                      , total )
AS
SELECT empId
     , Salary
     , Salary
FROM emp ;
```

Then query on that view like

```
SELECT empId
     , Salary
     , total 
FROM xx_emp_v ;
```

Your output will be :

```
 empId  Salary   Total
  1       10000   10000
  2       20000   20000
```

Comment: Can I do it in Single Select Statement ?